# How do I run a slow running batch Asynchronously, specifically a SVN post-commit?

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, post-commit

I have a slow running batch file that compiles a log of changes and then emails a user. I would like it not to cause the user's commits to perform slowly in TortoiseSVN.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
SET DIR=%REPOS%/hooks
SET PATH=%PATH%;%DIR%;C:\Utils 
SET WORKING_COPY=C:\path\to\local\copy\
SET SITENAME=MySiteName
SET SMTP_SERVER=11.11.11.11
SET EMAIL_TO=my@email.email
SET EMAIL_FROM=my@email.email
SET SUBJECT=SVN Update - %SITENAME% - rev %REV% - %REPOS%

svn cleanup %WORKING_COPY%
svn update %WORKING_COPY%


ECHO The following changes were made to the code: > %DIR%/email.txt
ECHO. >> %DIR%/email.txt


svn log %WORKING_COPY% -v -r "%REV%" >> %DIR%/email.txt


svn diff %WORKING_COPY% -c "%REV%" --no-diff-deleted >> %DIR%/email.txt


sendEmail -s %SMTP_SERVER% -t %EMAIL_TO% -f %EMAIL_FROM% -u "%SUBJECT%" -o message-file=%DIR%/email.txt
```

I realised that this was running slowly, so I moved it to another file "email-changes.bat" and created a simple batch to call this batch asynchronously.

```
@ECHO OFF
#START %1\hooks\email-changes.bat %1 %2
echo 'fired' > %1\hooks\test.log
```

If I comment out the "START" line it runs and finishes instantly. If I remove the comment it takes forever to complete. I thought that should allow the post-commit to return to SVN quickly.

Is there any way I can get the code to not hang in Subversion, but still complete the emailing task in the background?

Comment: Yes looking at this, I should really go "post-commit > MSMQ > update & email" that way I won't get any nasty collisons if 2 people check in at once.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the real hook script in a separate process:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd.exe /c START %1\hooks\email-changes.bat %1 %2
echo 'fired' > %1\hooks\test.log
```

if that doesn't work, find a tool that can start another bat file in a separate process/thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work - but big respect to you Stefan for all your work in TortoiseSVN.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190944/how-to-spawn-several-processes-from-the-windows-shell-and-wait-for-them-all-to-co   it should work: start cmd /c proc1.bat

Comment: Commenting out the cmd.exe line takes a few seconds to complete, but putting back in takes 1 minute 30 - and I always recieev the email before the command completes implying it's not working.